# How to add unallocated space to root partition

Tags: gparted

I have a partition that I would like to make bigger with the unallocated space I have, I have this Ubuntu system installed alongside Windows 10 which is 172.30GiB from the attached picture.

I have booted from USB and started GParted and right clicked on the ubuntu partition which is ext4, but I am not sure how to make it bigger with the unallocated space as the pop-up window does not show any free space, any help is appreciated, thanks.[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resize first the extended partition

For an unknown reason, it does not take all the remaining space.

So click on sda3/extended and resize it to its maxium.

Then you will be able to resize the sda6 partition as you expect.

Comment: the sda3/extended has the resize option disabled

Comment: any more ideas on this?

Comment: the swap miht be used. TRy to unmount it via gparted or via the cli with `swapoff /dev/sda5`. If this doe snot work you will have to go harcore at the cli with fdisk command with which you can't fail if you want to avoid a disaster

Comment: I can now resize the extended

Comment: It worked, I have managed to resize /dev/sda5 and it did it successfully!, thanks so much, now I guess I can turn back on the swap right?